# CORS POST request not working. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. What is wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xmlhttprequest, sencha-touch, cors

I am sending POST request from Sencha to Rails. While i am testing it using RestClient Application it gives "200 OK". But when i send request from Sencha app this returns an error given below:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://appointmedoc.herokuapp.com/login.json?_dc=1385013964033.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

While in my rails code application.rb

```
 after_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers


def cors_set_access_control_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin']      = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods']     = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age']           = '1728000'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
  end
```

Now what to do anybody?

Answer (score 4):

Do yourself a favor and handle CORS at the Rack level rather than at the controller level.  I recommend rack-cors - https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors .  Shouldn't take more than 10 minutes to set up.

It's possible that a before_filter is stopping the action from executing, in which case I'm not sure that the after_filter will run.

Comment: what if i want to do it without rack-cors? infact i have seen applications working fine by using this.

Comment: I'm sure you have.  But in my opinion it's a bad idea.  It's complex, poorly understood by most implementors, and leads to problems like the one you're encountering.  Honestly I have no idea why anyone would feel it necessary to do CORS at the controller level - it's so clearly a concern that belongs in Rack middleware.  And with the right middleware it takes 10 minutes to set up - almost certainly less time than you've spent wrestling with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Handling it on Rack Level:

Install:

https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors

```
# application.rb

# This allows requests from all origins, with all methods.
config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options]
  end
end
```

Answer (score -2):

I bet you have `https-everywhere` installed. Either disable https everywhere for heroku (go to that url then click the icon in the address bar) or load the https url directly.